# Generated code ignores 404 response status in open api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

I have following openApi:

```
 /users/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      operationId:...
      summary: ...
      parameters:
        - name: id
          required: true
          in: path
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
      responses:
        200:
          description: user object
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
        404:
          description: user not found
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
```

And generated code is:

```
...
public interface UserApi {
     ...
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/users/{id}",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    ResponseEntity<UserDto> retrieveUser(
        @Parameter(name = "id", description = "", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("id") String id
    );
```

**libs versions:**

```
plugins {
    java  
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "6.3.0"
}
...
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")
```

I don't understand why return type is `ResponseEntity<UserDto>`

What is expected implementation for this interface ? how could I return 404 response with custom error body?

Answer (score 0):

*how could I return 404 response with custom error body?

You could return something like this:

```
if(notFound){
  return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: The key point of my question that codegen generates response type `ResponseEntity<UserDto>` and your code will lead to compile error